# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if' SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get result5 = 1 in case average of operating cashflow is <=0 or average of top 3 operating cashflow is <=0. The Error message says incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

```
begin
   declare @OperatingCashflow5 int
   declare @OperatingCashflow3 int
   declare @result5 int

   select @OperatingCashflow5 = AVG(hpd.TotalCashFromOperations)
   from HistoricalFinPerformanceDataStagingGlobal hpd
   where hpd.companyid = @companyid

   select @OperatingCashflow3 = AVG(hpd.TotalCashFromOperations)
   from (
     select top (3) hpd.TotalCashFromOperations 
     from   HistoricalFinPerformanceDataStagingGlobal hpd 
     where hpd.companyid = @companyid
   )

   if @OperatingCashflow5 <= 0 OR @OperatingCashflow3 <= 0 
   begin
      select @result5 = 1
   end
   else
   begin
      select @result5 = 0
   end 
end
```

Comment: you need to give an alias to the derived table: `from (select top (3) hpd.TotalCashFromOperations from   HistoricalFinPerformanceDataStagingGlobal hpd where hpd.companyid = @companyid) t`

Comment: On a sidenote: `TOP` without `ORDER BY`? So you pick three records arbitrarily, calculate their average cash amount and compare that with the overall average cash amount (that you call OperatingCashflow5; whatever that 5 may stand for). Is this on purpose? It doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's MUCH easier to see the problem when you take a moment to format the code.

In this case, you have a nested SELECT statement, and a nested select must have an *alias*. All you have to do is add a single letter (*any* letter) after the closing parentheses:

```
begin
   declare @OperatingCashflow5 int
   declare @OperatingCashflow3 int
   declare @result5 int

   select @OperatingCashflow5 = AVG(hpd.TotalCashFromOperations)
   from HistoricalFinPerformanceDataStagingGlobal hpd
   where hpd.companyid = @companyid

   select @OperatingCashflow3 = AVG(hpd.TotalCashFromOperations)
   from (
     select top (3) hpd.TotalCashFromOperations 
     from   HistoricalFinPerformanceDataStagingGlobal hpd 
     where hpd.companyid = @companyid
   ) hpd -- <<<< Need a name here

   if @OperatingCashflow5 <= 0 OR @OperatingCashflow3 <= 0 
   begin
      select @result5 = 1
   end
   else
   begin
      select @result5 = 0
   end 
end
```

I suspect there are other problems with that specific select query, as well.

Comment: Yeah, in particular the fact that `top` without `order by` is just asking for trouble.